# element not found in selenium testing

Tags: java, selenium

I have exported test case from Selenium IDE in java format. The problem is that when I want to run it there is an error of "element not found" and I want to fix it in my java file. I added assersion but the try and catch that I added cath all the errors, so when I add an irrelevant element which I do not have on my page the test pass. I want to use `isElementPresent` function instead of try and catch. Any idea of how to use it and fix this error? Thanks!

```
public void testUser() {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("users")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("createNewButton")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("name")).clear();
                        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("USER1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123");
            driver.findElement(By.id("addUserButton")).click();
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Delete user')])[3]"))
                    .click();
            driver.findElement(
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
!driver.findElements(locator).isEmpty()
```

But in this case it's better to use [Html Elements](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) Library for clear code.

For example

```
WebElementMatchers.exists([yourElement])
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I had multiple elements? for example I have username and password and userbutton. I should write something like: if(!driver.findElements(password).isEmpty()) then  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123"); ? and the same for username ?

Comment: You can do it as you described, but it is not clear way. Use Html Elements Library. You can describe your login form like an object and comfortably use it. Look at examples on github link. The code will be looking like loginForm.password.type("login").

Comment: Also I'm interested why your expected elements are not appearing? May be you should simply wait for their appearance. It's bad way to skip action if you can't find element. You login field can disappear, but your test will pass in this case.

Comment: I cannot change the HTML elements now, and beside that changing to driver.findElements(locator).isEmpty() raised errors